# Is $\alpha = \pi^2$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am working on a problem that asks if $\alpha = \pi^2$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ (that is "$\mathbb{Q}$ adjoin $\pi$"). I did an identical problem right before that asks for the same thing but just for the field $\mathbb{Q}$, where I concluded that $\pi^2$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. I am leaning towards that $\pi^2$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ simply because $\pi \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, but I am not sure that should be the right reason even if it may be true.

Comment: $f(X) = X - \pi^2$ is solved by $\alpha = \pi^2$ and all of its coefficients lie in $\Bbb{Q}(\pi)$.  Therefore, $\alpha$ is definitely algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}(\pi)$ by one of the usual definitions of algebraic.

Comment: $\pi^2$ is an *element* of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Every element $\alpha$ of a field is algebraic over the field, as it satisfies the polynomial $x-\alpha$.

Comment: Is it also true that $x - \pi^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi)[x]$?

Comment: Just unwind the definitions of those symbols, Noel, and see for yourself.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(\pi)$ means the smallest **subfield** of $\Bbb{C}$ containing $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\pi$. it is immediate that it contains $\pi^2$.

Comment: Have you worked it out, Noel?

Comment: Are you still here, Noel?

Comment: Hello, sorry. I do understand. Since $\pi \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ then $\pi^2$ must be in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Thank you for all the help!